# Carrinho de compra armazenar no cliente ou server?

Tags: javascript, php, c#

Qual melhor forma de armazenar os itens de um carrinho de compra?

No próprio `javascript`, no lado cliente ou numa sessão no server, seja usando `$_SESSION(php)` ou `Session["sessao"](C#`)

Qual seria melhor? mais seguro e melhor usual para o usuário?

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação você está usando? PHP ou C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na sessão ou em um cookie.

Se você salva no JavaScript, primeiro não vai funcionar se o usuário tiver desabilitado JavaScript, segundo se o browser ou o computador "travar" ele perde todo o seu carrinho (você pode mitigar isso usando `localStorage` - quando suportado).

Se você usa a sessão, aí depende: o que acontece se o usuário fecha o browser (intencionalmente ou não - mesmo caso acima)? Se todos os dados forem apagados ao final da sessão, então há o mesmo problema. E a performance pode ser pior, se você precisar acessar o banco de dados cada vez que o usuário incluir um item novo.

### Usabilidade

Um problema comum com carrinhos de compra é o que acontece quando o usuário abre mais de uma aba ao mesmo tempo, ou usa o botão "Voltar" - nesses casos, o que está aparecendo na tela é uma coisa, o que realmente está no carrinho pode ser outra coisa. Pessoalmente, não sei qual será a expectativa do usuário: a) que o carrinho esteja exatamente igual ele está vendo na tela; ou: b) que o que ele fez numa aba esteja "salvo" de alguma forma, mesmo quando ele mexe na outra. A forma como você implementa tem impacto em um ou outro cenário.

O melhor que tenho a sugerir nesse caso é incluir um token aleatório nos formulários de submissão (por exemplo, como um *hidden input*) e sempre comparar esse token com aquele do carrinho antes de executar uma ação. Se forem diferentes, mostre a mesma página de novo pro usuário, atualizada - de modo que ele esteja vendo o carrinho correto antes da ação ser feita de fato.

### Segurança

Se você estiver usando `https` como espero que esteja, não faz muita diferença como é armazenado. Você pode assinar os dados do cookie, no servidor, se quiser evitar que o cliente mexa nos valores inapropriadamente (inclusive, é assim que muitas frameworks fazem para manter dados da sessão num cookie - e não no BD - sem comprometer a segurança do site), mas isso pode nem ser necessário.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação @mgibsonbr, só em relação aos cookie, se ele tentou fazer uma compra e fechou o site, é por que não quis naquela hora, então não vejo motivo dele deixar salvo sua ultima tentativa de compra, além que teria que expirar esse cookie depois de X tempo.

Acho a sessão uma forma bem válida, mas eu poderia usar objeto anonimo não ? para não ter que buscar sempre no banco aquele produto, o que acha? No mais muito bacana sua resposta

Comment: @Rod Pois é, eu não sei responder o que os usuários esperariam: manter salvo ou apagar tudo. Acho que cada um espera uma coisa diferente dos sites/programas... Quanto a usar "objeto anônimo", desculpe mas não sei do que se trata. Fala de alguma coisa na cache, em memória?

Answer (score 5):

No server.

Um dos motivos seria que a variável `Session` evapora quando o usuário sai do site ou fecha o browser. Neste caso, seria interessante que o site "lembrasse" da última tentativa de compra feita pelo usuário.